# displaying image with fancybox in ie

Tags: fancybox

I'm using fancybox library but when i display an image with fancybox method the result image has a bad render
The problem is only with internet explorer (ie). works fine with chrome.

The image looks like this

[bad render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F9oN.png)

The fancybox.js version is: 2.1.5 (Fri, 14 Jun 2013)
The jquery library version is: jquery-2.1.1.min.js

Am I using an incorrect fancybox library?
Am I using an incorrect jquery library?
the library is not compatible with ie?

Best regards
Jorge

Comment: Maybe there is something with your images, could you show some sample?

Comment: Both files, image 1 and image 2 are stored in sql server database in a binary column. (not retrieving both images from a local folder).  So I suspect that when I load all images in browser the are so heavy that crashes. That could be the problem?

Comment: So, you are using base64? Then yes, this is a know issue of older IE.

Comment: Yes Janis I'm using that code: 
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Product.ThumbnailImage);
var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
<img src="@imgSrc" />